# Writing on beamer Zoom slides

Tags: beamer

I am using beamer slides on Zoom.  I would like to write more onto any given slide as I go along. How do I do this?

Comment: This is not really related to LaTeX, as it is a viewer issue. I'll vote to close. However, it seems to be possible for any pdf that you screen share through Zoom to add annotations/writing, see for example https://www.andnextcomesl.com/2020/04/how-to-make-any-pdf-interactive-on-zoom.html or the official Zoom help center https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115005706806-Using-annotation-tools-on-a-shared-screen-or-whiteboard.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about LaTeX but about the capabilities of a screen share application.

Comment: Try searching for pdf annotation instead.